# A Stirling number identity representing the second-order Eulerian numbers.

Tags: stirling-numbers, eulerian-numbers

Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik give in
[CMath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics)
a thorough introduction to the Stirling numbers.
On table 250 and table 251, they compile two pages of
Stirling number identities.

Of course, there are many more such identities. We give here one
which is not included and which we could not find anywhere else
(which means little), but Knuth would perhaps like.
They can be proved with the techniques from CMath. Maybe someone
enjoys showing us the proof?

As in CMath, the Stirling cycle numbers are unsigned.
{n, k} and [n, k] are defined for 0 <= k <= n, and for this
range the following identity holds:

$$ \sum \limits_{j\,=\,0}^{k} (-1)^{k-j}\binom{2n+1}{k-j}
{n+j \brace j}
= \sum \limits_{j\,=\,0}^{n-k} (-1)^j \binom{2n+1}{j}
{n+m \brack m} $$

For better readability we use the shortcut $ m = n-k-j+1$.

References to the OEIS are [A132393](https://oeis.org/A132393), [A048993](https://oeis.org/A048993), and [A340556](https://oeis.org/A340556).

Comment: Two comments: 1) You should note that $m$ depends on $j,$ so the shortcut can be a little deceiving. 2) This has the flavor of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_number#Symmetric_formulae,
you can check more here: https://www.ams.org/journals/proc/1960-011-03/S0002-9939-1960-0114769-1/S0002-9939-1960-0114769-1.pdf

Comment: Both sides of the identity would be equal to the same second order Eulerian number, but I believe there is a typo : shouldn't it be ${n+j \brace j}$ instead of  ${2n+j \brace j}$ on the lhs ?

Comment: Thanks René! Typo corrected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We seek to show that with $0\le k\le n$ the following identity holds:

$$\sum_{j=0}^k (-1)^{k-j} {2n+1\choose k-j} {n+j\brace j} =
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} (-1)^j {2n+1\choose j} {2n-k-j+1\brack n-k-j+1}.$$

We will start with the LHS. The chapter 6.2 on Eulerian Numbers
of *Concrete Mathematics* by Knuth et al. proposes the formula

$${n\brace m} = (-1)^{n-m+1} \frac{n!}{(m-1)!} \sigma_{n-m}(-m)$$

where $\sigma_n(x)$ is a Stirling polynomial and we have the identity

$$\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^x
= x \sum_{n\ge 0} \sigma_n(x+n) z^n.$$

We get

$$[z^{n-m}] \left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^x
= x \sigma_{n-m}(x+n-m)$$

and hence

$$[z^{n-m}] \left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n}
= -n \sigma_{n-m}(-m)$$

which implies that for $n\ge m\ge 1$

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n\brace m} = (-1)^{n-m} \frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!}
[z^{n-m}] \left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n}.}$$

This gives for the LHS

$$\sum_{j=1}^k (-1)^{k-j} {2n+1\choose k-j}
(-1)^n \frac{(n+j-1)!}{(j-1)!} [z^n] 
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n-j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n] 
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n-1}
[w^{k-1}] (1+w)^{2n+1}
\\ \times \sum_{j=1}^k {n+j-1\choose n} (-1)^{j-1} w^{j-1}
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-j+1}.$$

Now the coefficient extractor in $w$ enforces the upper limit of the
sum and we may extend $j$ to infinity, getting

$$(-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n] 
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n-1}
[w^{k-1}] (1+w)^{2n+1}
\frac{1}{(1+w/(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}))^{n+1}}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
[w^{k-1}] (1+w)^{2n+1}
\frac{1}{(w+\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z})^{n+1}}.$$

Continuing,

$$ (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
[w^{n+k}] (1+w)^{2n+1}
\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{w} \frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z})^{n+1}}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
[w^{n+k}] (1+w)^{2n+1}
\sum_{q\ge 0} {n+q\choose n} (-1)^q \frac{1}{w^q}
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^q
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n] 
\sum_{j=n+k}^{2n+1} {2n+1\choose j} 
{n+j-(n+k)\choose n} (-1)^{j-(n+k)} 
\\ \times
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{j-(n+k)}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n] 
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} {2n+1\choose j+n+k} 
{n+j\choose n} (-1)^{j} 
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n!  
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} {2n+1\choose j+n+k} 
{n+j\choose n} (-1)^{j} [z^{n+j}] 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n!  
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} {2n+1\choose j+n+k} 
{n+j\choose n} (-1)^{j} 
\\ \times \frac{j!}{(n+j)!} \times (n+j)! [z^{n+j}] 
\frac{1}{j!} \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} 
{2n+1\choose j+n+k} (-1)^j {n+j\brack j}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} \sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} 
{2n+1\choose 2n-j+1} (-1)^{n-k-j+1} {2n-k-j+1\brack n-k-j+1}
\\ = \sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} 
{2n+1\choose j} (-1)^j {2n-k-j+1\brack n-k-j+1}.$$

The Stirling number is zero for $j=n-k+1$ and we get at last

$$\sum_{j=0}^{n-k} 
{2n+1\choose j} (-1)^j {2n-k-j+1\brack n-k-j+1}.$$

This is the RHS and we have the claim.

Comment: Great answer! Many thanks for this instructive contribution. (+1)

Comment: Thanks. I very much enjoyed working on it.