# An associated Stirling number identity related to the second-order Eulerian numbers.

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, eulerian-numbers

A similar Stirling number identity representing the second-order Eulerian numbers
can be found at this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4034224).

We denote the *associated Stirling cycle numbers* as $\left[\!\left[ n\atop  k\right] \! \right] $
[A008306](https://oeis.org/A008306), [A106828](https://oeis.org/A106828)
and the *associated Stirling set numbers* as $\left\{\!\! \left\{ n\atop  k\right\} \!\! \right\} $ [A008299](https://oeis.org/A008299), [A137375](https://oeis.org/A137375).
*Second-order Eulerian numbers* as we use them are defined in [A340556](https://oeis.org/A340556). They differ slightly from the second-order Eulerian numbers as defined by Graham, Knuth, and Patashnik in [CMath](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concrete_Mathematics).

In the range $0 \le k \le n$ the following identity holds:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-j} \binom{n-j}{k-j} 
\left\{ \!\! \left\{ n+j\atop j\right\} \!\! \right\} = 
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} (-1)^{n-k-j+1} \binom{n-j}{k-1} 
\left[\! \left[ n+j\atop j\right] \! \right] $$

Maybe someone enjoys showing us the proof?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We seek to show that with $0\le k\le n$ the following identity holds:

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-j} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\left\{ \!\! \left\{ n+j\atop j\right\} \!\! \right\} = 
\sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} (-1)^{n-k-j+1} {n-j\choose k-1} 
\left[\! \left[ n+j\atop j\right] \! \right] $$

where we have associated Stirling numbers of the first and second kind.

Now from the combinatorial meaning of these numbers (cancel fixed
points resp. singleton sets) we have that

$$\left[\! \left[ n\atop k\right] \! \right] =
\sum_{q=0}^k (-1)^q {n\choose q} {n-q\brack k-q}$$

and

$$\left\{ \!\! \left\{ n\atop k\right\} \!\! \right\} = 
\sum_{q=0}^k (-1)^q {n\choose q} {n-q\brace k-q}.$$

Consult    [OEIS    A008306](https://oeis.org/A008306)    and    [OEIS
A008299](https://oeis.org/A008299) for more information.  We will only
use  the second  of  these but  we  show the  pair  to illustrate  the
similarity in their construction  (PIE). The combinatorial classes for
these      are     $\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm
#1{\small     #2}}}    \textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{CYC}_{\ge
2}(\mathcal{Z}))$ and $\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{U}\times\textsc{SET}_{\ge
2}(\mathcal{Z})).$

We start with the LHS and obtain

$$\sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-j} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\sum_{q=0}^j (-1)^q {n+j\choose q} {n+j-q\brace j-q}.$$

With $n\ge 1$ this is

$$(-1)^k \sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\sum_{q=1}^j (-1)^q {n+j\choose j-q} {n+q\brace q}.$$

Recall e.g. from *Concrete Mathematics* chapter 6.2. that

$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
{n\brace m} = (-1)^{n-m} \frac{(n-1)!}{(m-1)!}
[z^{n-m}] \left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n}.}$$

We find for the LHS

$$(-1)^k \sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\sum_{q=1}^j (-1)^q {n+j\choose j-q}
(-1)^n \frac{(n+q-1)!}{(q-1)!} [z^n]
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n-q}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n-1}
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\\ \times
\sum_{q=1}^j (-1)^{q-1} {n+j\choose j-q}
{n+q-1\choose q-1}
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-q+1}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n-1}
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\\ \times [w^{j-1}] (1+w)^{n+j}
\sum_{q=1}^j (-1)^{q-1} w^{q-1}
{n+q-1\choose q-1}
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-q+1}.$$

Now the coefficient extractor enforces the upper limit of the inner sum
and we may extend $q$ to infinity, getting

$$(-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
\left(\frac{1}{z} \log\frac{1}{1-z}\right)^{-n-1}
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\\ \times [w^{j-1}] (1+w)^{n+j}
\frac{1}{(1+w/(\frac{1}{z}\log\frac{1}{1-z}))^{n+1}}
\\ = (-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
[w^{j-1}] (1+w)^{n+j}
\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{z}\log\frac{1}{1-z}+w)^{n+1}}.$$

The inner term is
$$[w^{j-1}] (1+w)^{n+j}
\frac{1}{(\frac{1}{z}(\log\frac{1}{1-z}-z)+1+w)^{n+1}}
\\ = [w^{j-1}] (1+w)^{j-1}
\frac{1}{(1+\frac{1}{1+w} \frac{1}{z}(\log\frac{1}{1-z}-z))^{n+1}}.$$

Re-expanding the series,

$$(-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
[w^{j-1}] (1+w)^{j-1} \\ \times
\sum_{q=j}^n {n+q\choose n} (-1)^q \frac{1}{(1+w)^q}
\left(\frac{1}{z}(\log\frac{1}{1-z}-z)\right)^q.$$

The upper limit on the inner sum results from $[z^n]$ because
$\frac{1}{z}  (\log\frac{1}{1-z}-z) = \frac{1}{2} z + \cdots$ and the
lower one from the fact that $[w^{j-1}] (1+w)^{j-1-q} = 0$ when $1\le 
q\le j-1$; $q=0$ produces a constant. Continuing,

$$(-1)^{n-k+1} n! [z^n]
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
[w^{j-1}] \\ \times
\sum_{q=j}^n {n+q\choose n} (-1)^q \frac{1}{(1+w)^{q-(j-1)}}
\left(\frac{1}{z}(\log\frac{1}{1-z}-z)\right)^q
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} n! [z^n]
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\sum_{q=j}^n {n+q\choose n} (-1)^{q-j} {q-1\choose q-j}
\left(\frac{1}{z}(\log\frac{1}{1-z}-z)\right)^q
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} n!
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\sum_{q=j}^n {n+q\choose n} (-1)^{q-j} {q-1\choose q-j}
[z^{n+q}] \left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}-z\right)^q
\\ = (-1)^{n-k} n!
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\sum_{q=j}^n {n+q\choose n} (-1)^{q-j} {q-1\choose q-j}
\\ \times \frac{q!}{(n+q)!}
\times (n+q)! [z^{n+q}] \frac{1}{q!} 
\left(\log\frac{1}{1-z}-z\right)^q
\\ = (-1)^{n-k}
\sum_{j=1}^{k} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\sum_{q=j}^n (-1)^{q-j} {q-1\choose q-j}
\left[\! \left[ n+q\atop q\right] \! \right].$$

It remains to simplify the binomial coefficients:

$$(-1)^{n-k}
\sum_{j=1}^{k} [u^k] u^j (1+u)^{n-j}
\sum_{q=j}^n (-1)^{q-j} {q-1\choose q-j}
\left[\! \left[ n+q\atop q\right] \! \right].$$

We see that we may raise $j$ to $n$ owing to $[u^k]$:

$$(-1)^{n-k}
\sum_{j=1}^{n} [u^k] u^j (1+u)^{n-j}
\sum_{q=j}^n (-1)^{q-j} {q-1\choose q-j}
\left[\! \left[ n+q\atop q\right] \! \right]
\\ = (-1)^{n-k}
\sum_{q=1}^n \left[\! \left[ n+q\atop q\right] \! \right]
[u^k] (1+u)^n \sum_{j=1}^q {q-1\choose q-j} (-1)^{q-j}
u^j (1+u)^{-j}.$$

The inner term is
$$[u^k] (1+u)^n \frac{u^q}{(1+u)^q} 
\sum_{j=0}^{q-1} {q-1\choose j} (-1)^{j}
\frac{(1+u)^j}{u^j}
\\ = [u^k] (1+u)^{n-q} u^q
\left(1-\frac{1+u}{u}\right)^{q-1}
\\ = [u^k] (1+u)^{n-q} u  (-1)^{q-1}
= (-1)^{q-1} [u^{k-1}] (1+u)^{n-q}.$$

This yields

$$\sum_{q=0}^{n-k+1} (-1)^{n-k-q+1} {n-q\choose k-1}
\left[\! \left[ n+q\atop q\right] \! \right]$$

which is  the claim. (Here we  must have $n-q\ge k-1$  or $n-k+1\ge q$
else  the binomial  coefficient vanishes  and we  may lower  the upper
limit from $n$ to $n-k+1.$)

Comment: Impressive! Is there any hope to generalize this case (k=2) to general k for the classes SET(U x CYC_{>=k}(Z)) and SET(U x SET_{>=k}(Z))?