# Difference of the Stirling cycle numbers and the Stirling set numbers

Tags: combinatorics, stirling-numbers, eulerian-numbers

Denote by $\left\langle\!\! \left\langle k\atop  j\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle$ the second-order Eulerian numbers [A340556](https://oeis.org/A340556). Define
$$ \left| n\atop  k\right| = \sum_{j=0}^k \left( \binom{n + j - 1}{2k} - \binom{n + k - j}{2k} \right) \left\langle\!\! \left\langle k\atop  j\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle .$$
Observe that the difference between the Stirling cycle numbers and the Stirling set numbers can be expressed as:
$$ \left[ n\atop k\right] -  \left\{ n\atop  k\right\} = \left| n\atop n- k\right| \quad (0 \le k \le n)$$

It is surprising that the difference between the two Stirling numbers had no entry in the OEIS -- until today! Now they are [A341102](https://oeis.org/A341102). But what we still need is an independent combinatorial interpretation of these numbers. Who knows one?

Who is willing to delight the combinatorists among us with a proof of this identity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We seek to show that with $0\le k\le n$ the following identity holds:

$${n\brack n-k} - {n\brace n-k} =
\sum_{j=0}^k \left({n+j-1\choose 2k} - {n+k-j\choose 2k}\right)
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle k\atop  j
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle.$$

We will use the following  two representations of the Eulerian numbers
of the second  order in terms of associated  Stirling numbers (consult
[MSE                                                              link
4037172](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4037172/)):

$$ \sum_{j=0}^{k} (-1)^{k-j} {n-j \choose k-j} 
\left\{ \!\! \left\{ n+j\atop j\right\} \!\! \right\} = 
\left\langle\!\! \left\langle n\atop  k\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
=\sum_{j=0}^{n-k+1} (-1)^{n-k-j+1} {n-j\choose k-1} 
\left[\! \left[ n+j\atop j\right] \! \right] $$

We get for the first piece

$$\sum_{j=1}^k {n+j-1\choose 2k} 
\sum_{p=0}^{k-j+1} (-1)^{k-j-p+1} {k-p\choose j-1}
\left[\! \left[ k+p\atop p\right] \! \right]
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left[\! \left[ k+p\atop p\right] \! \right]
(-1)^{k-p+1} 
\sum_{j=1}^{k+1-p} (-1)^j {n+j-1\choose 2k}
{k-p\choose j-1}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left[\! \left[ k+p\atop p\right] \! \right]
(-1)^{k-p} [z^{2k}] (1+z)^n
\sum_{j=1}^{k+1-p} (-1)^{j-1} (1+z)^{j-1}
{k-p\choose j-1}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left[\! \left[ k+p\atop p\right] \! \right]
(-1)^{k-p} [z^{2k}] (1+z)^n
(1-(1+z))^{k-p}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left[\! \left[ k+p\atop p\right] \! \right]
[z^{k+p}] (1+z)^n
= \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left[\! \left[ k+p\atop p\right] \! \right]
{n\choose k+p}.$$

Now this last piece evaluates  combinatorially to ${n\brack n-k}$ when
written  as $\left[\!  \left[ k+p\atop  p\right] \!  \right] {n\choose
n-k-p}$ namely we choose $n-k-p$  fixed points and split the remaining
$k+p$ elements  into $p$ cycles  of size at least  two for a  total of
$n-k$ cycles.  Here we  must have  $k+p\ge 2p$ or  $p\le k.$  (We have
classified by the number of fixed points).

We get for the second piece

$$\sum_{j=1}^k {n+k-j\choose 2k} 
\sum_{p=0}^{j} (-1)^{j-p} {k-p\choose j-p}
\left\{\! \left\{ k+p\atop p\right\} \! \right\}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left\{\! \left\{ k+p\atop p\right\} \! \right\}
(-1)^p \sum_{j=p}^k (-1)^j 
{n+k-j\choose 2k} {k-p\choose j-p}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left\{\! \left\{ k+p\atop p\right\} \! \right\}
\sum_{j=0}^{k-p} (-1)^j 
{n+k-j-p\choose 2k} {k-p\choose j}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left\{\! \left\{ k+p\atop p\right\} \! \right\}
[z^{2k}] (1+z)^{n+k-p} \sum_{j=0}^{k-p} (-1)^j 
(1+z)^{-j} {k-p\choose j}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left\{\! \left\{ k+p\atop p\right\} \! \right\}
[z^{2k}] (1+z)^{n+k-p}
\left(1-\frac{1}{1+z}\right)^{k-p}
\\ = \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left\{\! \left\{ k+p\atop p\right\} \! \right\}
[z^{2k}] (1+z)^{n} z^{k-p}
= \sum_{p=0}^k 
\left\{\! \left\{ k+p\atop p\right\} \! \right\}
{n\choose k+p}.$$

With this  piece we get exactly  the same reasoning as  with the first
one, namely it evaluates to ${n\brace n-k}$. We write it as $\left\{\!
\left\{ k+p\atop  p\right\} \! \right\} {n\choose  n-k-p}$ in choosing
the number  of singletons, of  which there are $n-k-p.$  The remaining
$k+p$ elements are distributed into $p$  disjoint sets of at least two
elements for  a total of $n-k$  sets. We once more  have the condition
that $k+p\ge  2p$ or $p\le  k.$ (We have  classified by the  number of
singleton sets.)

This concludes the argument.

Answer (score 3):

We can start from *Concrete Mathematics*, page 271, Equations (6.43) and (6.44). They are said to be obtained by induction on $n$, the second order Eulerian numbers are supposed to be defined by their basic recursion. With a slight modification, accounting for the difference in the definition of the second order Eulerian numbers between *Concrete Mathematics* and the *OEIS*, we have
$${x \brace x-k}= \sum_j \Big<\Big< \begin {align*} &k\\ j&+1 \end{align*}   \Big>\Big>{x+k-1-j\choose 2k} $$
$${x \brack x-k}= \sum_j \Big<\Big< \begin {align*} & k\\ j&+1 \end{align*}   \Big>\Big>{x+j\choose 2k} $$
Then $$ \left| x\atop  k\right| = {x \brack x-k}-{x \brace x-k}= \sum_j \Big<\Big< \begin {align*} &k\\ j&+1 \end{align*}   \Big>\Big>\left({x+j\choose 2k}-{x+k-j-1\choose 2k} \right) $$
Then $$ \left| x\atop  k\right| = \sum_j \Big<\Big< \begin {align*} &k\\ &j \end{align*}   \Big>\Big>\left({x+j-1\choose 2k}-{x+k-j\choose 2k} \right) $$