# The value of the second-order Eulerian polynomials at x = -1/2.

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, eulerian-numbers

Recently, the second-order Eulerian polynomials
$ \left\langle\!\left\langle x \right\rangle\!\right\rangle_n $
have been discussed on MSE [ [a](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040942) ,
 [b](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4043347) ].

$$ \left\langle\!\left\langle x \right\rangle\!\right\rangle_n = 
\sum_{k=0}^n \left\langle\!\!\left\langle n\atop k \right\rangle\!\!\right\rangle \, x^k $$

Here $\left\langle\!\!\left\langle n\atop k \right\rangle\!\!\right\rangle $
are the second-order Eulerian numbers [A340556](https://oeis.org/A340556).
The values of these polynomials at $ x = \frac12 $ generate a sequence
that represents the solution of Schröder's fourth problem
(see [MSE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4040942) and
[A000311](https://oeis.org/A000311)).

That's a pretty nice result that suggests the question:
Do the values of the polynomials at $ x = -\frac12$ (times $ 2^n $) also have
a combinatorial meaning? That this might indeed be the case is a conjecture
suggested by many examples of combinatorial polynomials. The reader can get
an impression for himself while browsing through the OEIS.

| Polynomials | P(x) | 2^nP(1/2) | 2^nP(-1/2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Laguerre | [A021009](https://oeis.org/A021009) | [A103194](https://oeis.org/A103194) | [A000262](https://oeis.org/A000262) |
| Motzkin | [A064189](https://oeis.org/A064189) | [A330796](https://oeis.org/A330796) | [A000244](https://oeis.org/A000244) |
| BigSchröder | [A080247](https://oeis.org/A080247) | [A065096](https://oeis.org/A065096) | [A239204](https://oeis.org/A239204) |
| StirlingSet | [A048993](https://oeis.org/A048993) | [A005493](https://oeis.org/A005493) | [A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110) |
| StirlingCycle | [A132393](https://oeis.org/A132393) | [A000254](https://oeis.org/A000254) | [A000774](https://oeis.org/A000774) |
| Eulerian 1st | [A173018](https://oeis.org/A173018) | [A180119](https://oeis.org/A180119) | [A001710](https://oeis.org/A001710) |

However, this question may not be easy to answer, so we ask a more concrete question.
The sequence $ 2^n \left\langle \!\left\langle - 1/2 \right\rangle \!\right\rangle_n $
can also be generated without reference to the second-order Eulerian polynomials by
series reversion.

$$ 2^n \left\langle\!\!\left\langle - \frac{1}{2} \right\rangle\!\!\right\rangle_n 
= (n + 1)!\, [x^{n+1}]\, \text{Reversion}\left(\frac{6x + \exp(3x) - 1}{9}\right) \quad (n \ge 0). $$

Can someone confirm this equation?

**Addendum:**

The general form of the reversion is described by:
$$ \left\langle\! \left\langle x \right\rangle\! \right\rangle_n = 
(n+1)!\, (1-t)^{2n + 1}\, [x^{n+1}]\, 
\operatorname{Reversion}_{x}(x + t - t \exp(x)) \quad (n \ge 0) $$

Comment: Mathematica: S := InverseSeries[Series[x + t - t Exp[x], {x, 0, 7}], x]; Table[(n+1)! (1-t)^(2n+1) Coefficient[S, x, n+1], {n, 0, 6}]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some comments. Seeking to invert

$$-\frac{1}{9} + \frac{2}{3} x + \frac{1}{9} \exp(3x) = z$$

we consult [Wikipedia on
LambertW](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)
to find  that the closed form solution to

$$x = a + b \exp(cx)$$

is given by

$$x = a - \frac{1}{c} W(-bc \exp(ac)).$$

We thus write

$$x = \frac{3}{2} z + \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{6} \exp(3x).$$

to obtain

$$\frac{1}{6} + \frac{3}{2} z
- \frac{1}{3} W((1/2)\times \exp((9/2)z+1/2))
\\ = \frac{1}{6} + \frac{3}{2} z
- \frac{1}{3} W(\exp((1+9z)/2)/2).$$

We have

$$W(z) = \sum_{m\ge 1} (-1)^{m-1} m^{m-1} \frac{z^m}{m!}$$

We then obtain for $n\ge 1$

$$-\frac{1}{3} (n+1)! [x^{n+1}]
\sum_{m\ge 1} (-1)^{m-1} \frac{m^{m-1}}{m!}
\frac{\exp(m/2)}{2^m} \exp(9mx/2)
\\ = \frac{1}{3}
\sum_{m\ge 1} (-1)^{m} \frac{m^{m+n}}{m!}
\frac{\exp(m/2)}{2^{m+n+1}} 9^{n+1}
\\ = \frac{3^{2n+1}}{2^{n+1}}
\sum_{m\ge 1} (-1)^{m} \frac{m^{m+n}}{m!}
\frac{\exp(m/2)}{2^{m}}
.$$

Using the notation from the cited post we get for our closed form

$$\frac{3^{2n+1}}{2^{n+1}} Q_n(-\exp(1/2)/2).$$

Now with $T(-\exp(1/2)/2) = -1/2$ we get with the cited identity

$$\frac{3^{2n+1}}{2^{n+1}}
\frac{1}{(3/2)^{2n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n \left\langle\!\! \left\langle n\atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}
\\ = 2^n \sum_{k=0}^n \left\langle\!\! \left\langle n\atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle
\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right)^{k}.$$

This is the claim. Note that with $n=0$ we get $Q_0(-\exp(1/2)/2) - 1$
from the series for a total of $\frac{3}{2} +
\frac{3}{2} (Q_0(-\exp(1/2)/2)-1) = \frac{3}{2} +
\frac{3}{2} \frac{1}{3/2} - \frac{3}{2} = 1$ which also agrees with
the polynomial.

**Concerning the addendum.** Inverting $x+t-t\exp(x)$ with respect to
$x$ we obtain

$$-W(- t \exp ( -t + z )) -t + z.$$

We then get for the proposed closed form with $n\ge 1$

$$- (1-t)^{2n+1} (n+1)! [x^{n+1}]
\sum_{m\ge 1} (-1)^{m-1} \frac{m^{m-1}}{m!}
(-1)^m t^m \exp(-tm) \exp(mx)
\\ = (1-t)^{2n+1}
\sum_{m\ge 1} \frac{m^{m+n}}{m!}
t^m \exp(-tm).$$

This is $(1-t)^{2n+1} Q_n(t\exp(-t)).$ Now we have $T(t\exp(-t)) = t$
so we obtain

$$(1-t)^{2n+1} \frac{1}{(1-t)^{2n+1}}
\sum_{k=0}^n \left\langle\!\! \left\langle n\atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle t^k
\\ = \sum_{k=0}^n \left\langle\!\! \left\langle n\atop k
\right\rangle\!\! \right\rangle t^k$$

as claimed. We get for $n=0$, that the coefficient on the singleton $z$
is $(1-t)$ for a total of $1-t+ (1-t) (Q_0(t\exp(-t))-1) = 1-t + (1-t)
t/(1-t) = 1$ which is the correct value.